# CSS Media Query not displaying desired output

Tags: css, media-queries, styling

When the viewport is larger than 992px, I'd like to display a grey line under the menu elements in the following two instances:

1. When a page is being actively visited, I want the line to stay in place
2. When a page is not being actively visited, I want the line to appear upon hovering

Here's my code (as instructed by Code Institute):

**General styling**

```css
/* Nav bar */

.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3a3a3a;
}
```

**Media Query**

```css
/* Media Query: laptops and desktops (992px and up) */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #menu a:hover {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3a3a3a;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: the `:hover` selector is working, but the line isn't staying in place upon actively visiting each page.

I'm quite new to CSS and web development overall, so I tried removing the general styling to see if the media query would work as expected. It did. I also tried adding an `:active` selector to the general styling, but that didn't work. Beyond those two things, I'm not entirely sure how to troubleshoot the issue, hence my question.

Thanks!

Comment: instead of the media query, for what you're trying to accomplish it probably makes more sense to use `@media (hover: hover)` . In terms of the other issue, the CSS portion of the .active class should work as written, so most likely that class isn't being applied correctly. Do you have a more complete code demo available?

Comment: Hi there, I checked in the meantime and realised it wasn't showing up due to the code all being written on one page. When I created separate pages and only added the classes to their corresponding pages, it worked. Thanks very much for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read how to use hover together with media queries from this [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) (CCS4 convention) .

Here is an example of how you can use hover inside media queries.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>News</title>
    <style>
      @media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (hover: hover) {
        #menu a:hover {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #3a3a3a;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="#">Try hovering over me! I get underline on Hover</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Hovering over me doesn't apply style</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As for your case (based on your code from link in comments):

1. case where you want "actively visited". You have to use either `:active` selector or `:visited` selector based on your need.
   Currently  your code has a `class="visited"` applied to all your links, which gives you the content of `.visited` permanently. If you use selector you will get desired output.

    I think you want to toggle between the links and show page below based on what is selected. I would recommend you use any scripting language to achieve that. Since it would be much easier. Refer to some navbar code's since you are new.
2. due to `.visited` having same code as hover you were not able to see any changes on hover. If you comment `.visited` or change it to an appropriate selector. It will work for you.

Comment: Hi Ashish, many thanks for your answer. It's difficult for me to identify the issue. If possible, I would appreciate it if you could also explain what was wrong with my code, so that I can correct it. I'm only asking because I tried your solution, and unfortunately, it's not working.

Comment: @criley Just add ```and (hover: hover)``` to your media query and try if it works for you. This worked for me on chrome. Other than that, check if your correctly accessing the element in CSS.

Comment: @criley https://codepen.io/kibnkqou-the-scripter/pen/BabNBag  checkout this code. Its working fine. and post your complete code. There might be an issue with your structure/ accessing the element correctly while applying media query. And do add what platform/browser you're using to check.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for sharing the above resource. I just had a look and wanted to add that the hover part is working, but the line isn't staying in place when each page is visited. As requested, here is my HTML and CSS code: https://codepen.io/c-hut/pen/WNmvexQ. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand why it's needed and why it should solve the problem, also after reading the MDN page. `hover: hover` may be useful to provide alternative interactions to users who can't hover, like different tooltips, but once the media query condition matches then it makes no difference for its content. So I'd like to understand better why it should have a different output

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina yeah, I just looked OPs code, that was not the issue, anyways, since CSS4, it's better to use ```(hover: hover)``` since it removes if state sticks like in mobile devices, since I was not sure of OPs environment. But you can definitely work without it.  @criley I looked at your code I think I found your issue, let me update the answer. Please Upvote and accept the answer if it helps.